# Does a chain attack's damage bonus apply to healing arts?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

During chain attacks there is a damage multiplier which increases how much damage attack arts do to an enemy. Does this damage bonus multiplier apply to healing arts?

[image: 150% damage bonus]

Answer (score 1):

Based on some testing while fighting regular and elite monsters, the "Chain Boost" does indeed affect healing arts. However, the boost is calculated differently with healing arts, resulting in only a few hundred points difference rather than thousands with combat arts.

Below is an image while fighting a standard monster (I'm currently controlling Mio as a Tactician). By using the AOE Healing Art "Stormy Skies", my units were healed anywhere between 573 and 591<sup>1</sup> points of HP.

[image: Mio Tactician, ~500/600 HP healing]

Below are two screenshots while also using Mio as a Tactician, and using "Stormy Skies" while doing a Chain Attack. The first screenshot has a 300% boost and the second screenshot has a 543% boost. The difference in healing between the 300% and 543% boost is negligible<sup>2</sup>, and "Stormy Skies" did in fact heal an additional ~150 HP during the chain attack.

[image: Mio Tactician, ~730 HP healing, 300% boost][image: Mio Tactician, ~730 HP healing, 543% boost]

---

<sup>1</sup> This number was the same while fighting a standard monster and elite monster, this was just the image I uploaded

<sup>2</sup> Again, this is probably due to how it calculated differently than combat arts. I plan on testing around with higher damage boosts to see how much this gets affected.

Comment: Maybe chain attacks give a buff to healing unrelated to the damage bonus percentage?

Comment: @Stevoisiak Quite possible. If that is true, then it's probably a hidden modifier